# How to get coefficient from logarithmic regression in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, regression

Suppose that I have two columns of data, `C1:C5` as inputs and `D1:D5` as responses, and I set a logarithmic trendline on the resulting scatterplot. As an example, set `C1:C5` to 1, 2, 3, 4, 5; and `D1:D5` as 1, 6, 9, 12, 13.

The trendline equation will be of the form **y = a ln(x) + b**, where **a** and **b** are constants. I know the formula to extract **b**: `INTERCEPT(C1:C5, D1:D5)`. What's the equivalent formula for **a**? Critically, `SLOPE` seems to be of no use here, because that would mean that the regression line is linear.

Using my example numbers above, the logarithmic regression, according to Excel, has the equation **y = 7.643 ln(x) + 0.8818**. To extract 0.8818, I can just use the formula `INTERCEPT(C1:C5, D1:D5)`. How specifically do I extract 7.643 from this regression equation? What's the formula I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was hiding in plain sight. Since we take the natural log of **x**, we just need to take that transformation when calculating the slope. Therefore, the slope can be calculated as:

`SLOPE(C1:C5, LN(D1:D5))`

Using the example data generates the desired slope of 7.643.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [the `LINEST()` function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/linest-function-84d7d0d9-6e50-4101-977a-fa7abf772b6d) and use `LN(known_x's)` isntead of just `known_x's`.

```
=INDEX(LINEST(known_y's,LN(known_x's)),1)
```

`LINEST()` returns an array of values, some of which are themselves an array. The first entry is an array of coefficients which is only really complicated if you have several different sets of `x` values you're inputting. You can use a very similar function to return the `b` value, too, since that will be the last term in the array of coefficients (i.e., the second term if you only feed in one set of `x` values).

```
=INDEX(LINEST(known_y's,LN(known_x's)),1,2)
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to put the formula directly on your graph output:[image]

Comment: Doesn't help if I need numerical access to the slope.